# Allow more than one python threads to use resource at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency

I am writing an application where I want to allow to more than one threads  to use the same resource at the same time. I don't understand how that could be achieved. At the moment, I have gone up to this point: I have two threads thread a and b and two locks. First the thread a runs and then thread b. I would like to have a third thread as well - which is not a problem - but I want thread a and b to execute concurrently and after they complete, allow to the third thread to assume control of the common resource.

```
from threading import Lock, Thread
import logging
import time


class SynchronizedThreads:

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize a list for threads.
        self.threads = []
        # Initialize lock objects.
        self.lock_a = Lock()
        self.lock_b = Lock()
        # Set the logging format.
        log_format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
        logging.basicConfig(format=log_format, level=logging.INFO, datefmt="%H:%M:%S")

    def thread_a(self):
        logging.info('Thread A is starting ...')
        logging.info('Thread A is waiting to acquire lock A.')
        self.lock_a.acquire()
        logging.info('Thread A has acquired lock A, performing some calculation...')
        time.sleep(2)
        logging.info('Thread A is waiting to acquire lock B.')
        self.lock_b.acquire()
        logging.info('Thread A has acquired lock B, performing some calculation...')
        time.sleep(2)
        logging.info('Thread A is releasing both locks.')
        self.lock_a.release()
        self.lock_b.release()

    def thread_b(self):
        logging.info('Thread B is starting...')
        logging.info('Thread B is waiting to acquire lock B.')
        self.lock_a.acquire()
        logging.info('Thread B has acquired lock B, performing some calculation...')
        time.sleep(5)
        logging.info('Thread B is waiting to acquire lock A.')
        self.lock_b.acquire()
        logging.info('Thread B has acquired lock A, performing some calculation...')
        time.sleep(5)
        logging.info('Thread B is releasing both locks.')
        self.lock_b.release()
        self.lock_a.release()

    def start_threads(self):
        for thread_func in [self.thread_a, self.thread_b]:
            self.threads.append(Thread(target=thread_func))
            self.threads[-1].start()

    def join_threads(self):
        for thread in self.threads:
            thread.join()

    
def main():
    sync_threads = SynchronizedThreads()
    sync_threads.start_threads()
    sync_threads.join_threads()
    logging.info('Finished')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a semaphore.  It can be thought of as a thread safe counter, so you have two things that need to be done, have the third thread wait on a semaphore twice.  If both thread A and B finish at the same time somehow, it'll work, but in this simple example, it will safely wait for them to finish one after the other:

```python
from threading import Lock, Thread, Semaphore
import logging
import time


class SynchronizedThreads:

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize a list for threads.
        self.threads = []
        # Initialize lock objects.
        self.lock_a = Lock()
        self.lock_b = Lock()
        self.sem = Semaphore(0)
        # Set the logging format.
        log_format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
        logging.basicConfig(format=log_format, level=logging.INFO, datefmt="%H:%M:%S")

    def thread_a(self):
        logging.info('Thread A is starting ...')
        logging.info('Thread A is waiting to acquire lock A.')
        self.lock_a.acquire()
        logging.info('Thread A has acquired lock A, performing some calculation...')
        time.sleep(2)
        logging.info('Thread A is waiting to acquire lock B.')
        self.lock_b.acquire()
        logging.info('Thread A has acquired lock B, performing some calculation...')
        time.sleep(2)
        logging.info('Thread A is releasing both locks.')
        self.lock_a.release()
        self.lock_b.release()
        logging.info("Thread A is signaling that it's done to the semaphore")
        self.sem.release()

    def thread_b(self):
        logging.info('Thread B is starting...')
        logging.info('Thread B is waiting to acquire lock B.')
        self.lock_a.acquire()
        logging.info('Thread B has acquired lock B, performing some calculation...')
        time.sleep(5)
        logging.info('Thread B is waiting to acquire lock A.')
        self.lock_b.acquire()
        logging.info('Thread B has acquired lock A, performing some calculation...')
        time.sleep(5)
        logging.info('Thread B is releasing both locks.')
        self.lock_b.release()
        self.lock_a.release()
        logging.info("Thread B is signaling that it's done to the semaphore")
        self.sem.release()

    def thread_c(self):
        logging.info('Thread C is starting...')
        # Two workers, wait for both of them
        expected_workers = 2
        for _ in range(expected_workers):
            logging.info('Thread C is waiting for the semaphore...')
            self.sem.acquire()
            logging.info("Thread C got the semaphore")
        logging.info("Thread C doing some work...")
        time.sleep(5)
        logging.info("Thread C all done")

    def start_threads(self):
        for thread_func in [self.thread_a, self.thread_b, self.thread_c]:
            self.threads.append(Thread(target=thread_func))
            self.threads[-1].start()

    def join_threads(self):
        for thread in self.threads:
            thread.join()

    
def main():
    sync_threads = SynchronizedThreads()
    sync_threads.start_threads()
    sync_threads.join_threads()
    logging.info('Finished')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```